# Add nodes dynamically to a D3 Tree layout request (on toggle)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

**Introduction:**
I am trying to extend d3 - tree layout.

I am trying to add new nodes via ajax/setTimeout on toggle event.

**What i have done:**
I have success with adding new nodes in sync:
https://jsfiddle.net/xfj875vc/1/

I changed only 2 parts of the code:

**Change 1 (added method which add new childs to a nodes without childs):**

    `function addNewNode(d, item) {
        d._children = d._children || [];
        d._children = d._children.concat(item);
    }`

**Change 2 (call to addNewNode when clicking for toggle, i am adding new node only for nodes without chilren):**

```
 var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) {

            // change start
            var newItem;

            if (!d._children || d._children.length === 0) {
                newItem = [
                    {
                        "name": "i am new",
                        "children": [
                            { "name": "i am new child 1"},
                            { "name": "i am new child 2"}
                        ]
                    }
                ];
                addNewNode(d, newItem);
            }
            // change end

            toggle(d); update(d);
        });
```

**2 problems:**

1. when adding a node with children, it's show it and expand everything, the childs should be minimized.
2. If i am trying to wrap the code in setTimeout, it add the children. however, the transition and the animation not work properly, d3 also expand the nested childs, you can see it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/xfj875vc/3/ (try to click more that once)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your method

```
   function addNewNode(d, item) {
        d._children = d._children || [];
        d._children = d._children.concat(item);
    }
```

- We have to understand over here that `d._children has values when collapsed` and `so d.children will be undefined`.
  And viceversa when a node is expanded. Thus i am not sure what you are trying to do in the above code.
- Secondly this will put an d._children.concat(item); array inside an array. Which is not expected thus i am doing the same with a for loop below.

should have been:

```
function addNewNode(d, item) {
      item.forEach(function(i){
        if(d._children)
            d._children.push(i)//will add child to the closed node      
        else 
            d.children.push(i)//will add child to expanded node.
      })
}
```

Next I am keeping a flag in the data to indicate that it does not need to be loaded via ajax on click.

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "loaded" : true, //so this node flare will not be loaded on click via ajax
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "loaded" : true,//so this node analytics will not be loaded on click via ajax
   "children": [...
```

Finally in my click function i ll load only when this flag is undefined.

```
.on("click", function(d) {

  if (d.loaded === undefined) {\\do ajax
    setTimeout(function() {
      var newItem;

      newItem = [{
        "name": "i am new",
        "children": [{
          "name": "i am new child 1"
        }, {
          "name": "i am new child 2"
        }]
      }];
      addNewNode(d, newItem);
      d.loaded = true;//mark it as loaded so it doesn't load next time
      console.log("called", d)

      toggle(d);
      update(d);

    }, 1000)
  } else {//already loaded so dont do ajax
      toggle(d);
      update(d);
  }
});
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9g291ys5/)

In case you want the loaded node to be collapsed.

You create a new node like this:

```
      newItem = [{
        "name": "i am new",
        "children": [{
          "name": "i am new child 1"
        }, {
          "name": "i am new child 2"
        }]
      }];
```

Instead of that do

```
      newItem = [{
        "name": "i am new",
        "_children": [{ //note its changed to _children to show collapsed
          "name": "i am new child 1"
        }, {
          "name": "i am new child 2"
        }]
      }];
```

Working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/9g291ys5/1/)

Hope this helps!